# vectorizing an R-loop with backward dependency

Tags: r, performance, vector, vectorization

I have a random vector `vec` and want make a new vector `L` without using a loop. New element of `L` depends on old elements of `L` and `vec`.

```
set.seed(0)

vec <- rnorm(20,0)
i = 2; 
N <- length(vec) -1
L <- numeric(N-1)
constant <- 0.6

while (i < N){  

  L[i] = vec[i + 1] - vec[i] - constant * L[i - 1]

  i <- i + 1          
}

L
#  [1]  0.0000000  1.6560326 -1.0509895 -0.2271942 -1.8182750  1.7023480 -0.3875622  0.5214906  2.0975262 -2.8995756  0.1771427
# [12] -0.4549334  1.1311555 -0.6884468  0.3007724  0.4832709 -1.4341071  2.1880687
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to compute values based on previous values the general purpose answer is *no, there is no way around a loop*.

In your case I would use a `for` loop. It's simpler.

```
M <- numeric(N - 1)
for(i in seq_len(N)[-N])
  M[i] = vec[i + 1] - vec[i] - constant*M[i - 1]

identical(L, M)
#[1] TRUE
```

Note the use of `seq_len`, not `2:(N - 1)`.

**Edit.**

I have timed the solutions by myself and by user 李哲源. The results are clearly favorable to my solution.

```
f1 <- function(vec, constant = 0.6){
  N <- length(vec) - 1
  M <- numeric(N - 1)
  for(i in seq_len(N)[-c(1, N)]){
    M[i] = vec[i + 1] - vec[i] - constant*M[i - 1]
  }
  M
}

f2 <- function(vec, constant = 0.6){
  dv <- diff(vec)
  c(0, c(stats::filter(dv[2:(length(dv) - 1)], -constant, "recursive")) )
}

L1 <- f1(vec)
L2 <- f2(vec)

identical(L, L1)
identical(L, L2)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  loop = f1(vec),
  filter = f2(vec)
)
```

On my PC the ratio of the medians gives my code 11 times faster.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
L[1] = 0
L[i] = -constant * L[i - 1] + (vec[i + 1] - vec[i]),  i = 2, 3, ...,
```

Let `dv <- diff(vec)`, the 2nd line becomes

```
L[i] = -constant * L[i - 1] + dv[i],  i = 2, 3, ...
```

an AR1 process with lag-1 auto-correlation `-constant` and innovation `dv[-1]`. AR1 process can be efficiently generated by `filter` with "recursive" method.

```
dv <- diff(vec)
L <- c(0, filter(dv[-1], -constant, "recursive"))

# [1]  0.0000000  1.6560326 -1.0509895 -0.2271942 -1.8182750  1.7023480
# [7] -0.3875622  0.5214906  2.0975262 -2.8995756  0.1771427 -0.4549334
#[13]  1.1311555 -0.6884468  0.3007724  0.4832709 -1.4341071  2.1880687
#[19] -2.9860629
```

I guess you mean `while (i <= N)` in your question. If you do want `i < N`, then you have to get rid of the last element above. Which can be done by

```
dv <- diff(vec)
L <- c(0, filter(dv[2:(length(dv) - 1)], -constant, "recursive"))
```

---

**hours later...**

I was brought to attention by [Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312427/r-vector-value-based-on-previous-element-without-loop/51312757#51312757)'s benchmark. For short `vec`, any method is fast enough. For long `vec`, `filter` is definitely faster, but practically suffers from coercion as `filter` expects and returns a "ts" (time series) object. It is better to call its workhorse C routine straightaway:

```
AR1_FILTER <- function (x, filter, full = TRUE) {
  n <- length(x)
  AR1 <- .Call(stats:::C_rfilter, as.double(x), as.double(filter), double(n + 1L))
  if (!full) AR1 <- AR1[-1L]
  AR1
  }

dv <- diff(vec)
L <- AR1_FILTER(dv[-1], -constant)
#L <- AR1_FILTER(dv[2:(length(dv) - 1)], -constant)
```

I am not interested in comparing `AR1_FILTER` with R-level loop. I will just compare it with `filter`.

```
library(microbenchmark)
v <- runif(100000)
microbenchmark("R" = c(0, filter(v, -0.6, "recursive")),
               "C" = AR1_FILTER(v, -0.6))

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
    R 6.803945 7.987209 11.08361 8.074241 9.131967 54.672610   100
    C 2.586143 2.606998  2.76218 2.644068 2.660831  3.845041   100
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about using Rcpp for this, but one of the answer mentioned `rfilter` built internally in R, so I had a check:

```
/* recursive filtering */
SEXP rfilter(SEXP x, SEXP filter, SEXP out)
{
   if (TYPEOF(x) != REALSXP || TYPEOF(filter) != REALSXP
       || TYPEOF(out) != REALSXP) error("invalid input");
    R_xlen_t nx = XLENGTH(x), nf = XLENGTH(filter);
    double sum, tmp, *r = REAL(out), *rx = REAL(x), *rf = REAL(filter);

    for(R_xlen_t i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    sum = rx[i];
    for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < nf; j++) {
        tmp = r[nf + i - j - 1];
        if(my_isok(tmp)) sum += tmp * rf[j];
        else { r[nf + i] = NA_REAL; goto bad3; }
    }
    r[nf + i] = sum;
    bad3:
    continue;
    }
    return out;
}
```

This function is already pretty look and I don't think I could write an Rcpp one to beat it with great improvement. I did a benchmark with this `rfilter` and the `f1` function in the accepted answer:

```
f1 <- function(vec, constant = 0.6){
  N <- length(vec) - 1
  M <- numeric(N - 1)
  for(i in seq_len(N)[-c(1, N)]){
    M[i] = vec[i + 1] - vec[i] - constant*M[i - 1]
  }
  M
}

AR1_FILTER <- function (x, filter, full = TRUE) {
  n <- length(x)
  AR1 <- .Call(stats:::C_rfilter, as.double(x), as.double(filter), double(n + 1L))
  if (!full) AR1 <- AR1[-1L]
  AR1
  }

f2 <- function (vec, constant) {
  dv <- diff(vec)
  AR1_FILTER(dv[2:(length(dv) - 1)], -constant)
  }

library(microbenchmark)

Bench <- function (n) {
  vec <- runif(n)
  microbenchmark("R" = f1(vec, 0.6), "C" = f2(vec, 0.6))
  }
```

For short vectors with length 100, I got

```
Bench(100)

Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
    R 68.098 69.8585 79.05593 72.456 74.6210 244.148   100
    C 66.423 68.5925 73.18702 69.793 71.1745 150.029   100
```

For large vectors with length 10000, I got

```
Bench(10000)

Unit: microseconds
 expr      min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
    R 6168.742 6699.9170 6870.277 6786.0415 6997.992 8921.279   100
    C  876.934  904.6175 1192.000  931.9345 1034.273 2962.006   100
```

Yeah, there is no way that R is going to beat a compiled language.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)


L2 <- c(0,lead(vec) - vec - constant * lag(L))
L2 <- L2[!is.na(L2)]
L2

 [1]  0.00000000  1.09605531 -0.62765133  1.81529867 -2.10535596  3.10864280 -4.36975556  1.41375965
 [9] -1.08809820  2.16767510 -1.82140234  1.14748512 -0.89245650  0.03962074 -0.10930073  1.48162072
[17] -1.63074832  2.21593009


all.equal(L,L2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: That only works if you already have the vector `L` produced by the OP's code. Try starting with `L <- numeric(N-1)`.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice I had not resetted L to `numeric(N-1)`